# Delete DF rows based on mixed condition (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete DF rows based on a mixed condition. My DF contains these columns:

```
DF['ID', 'SEQNO','DESCRIP'].
```

DF will have multiples rows for a given 'ID' but 'ID'+'SEQNO' combination is unique. Now suppose my DF is having this data:

```
ID  SEQNO   DESCRIP
A1  1   This is test
A1  2   To check DF
A1  3   XYZ
A1  4   ghj
B1  1   Hello, How are you.
B1  2   XYZ
B1  3   I am Fine
B1  4   Thank You.
B1  5   and you.
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  SEQNO   DESCRIP
A1  1   This is test
A1  2   To check DF
B1  1   Hello, How are you.
```

Here I want all the rows of an ID where SEQNO < the SEQNO where 'XYZ' has came for a given ID. I tried using the code below, but its very poor, and takes a long time:

```
rdf =  df[df['DESCRIP'].str.contains('XYZ', na=False, case=False )]

for i in range(rdf.shape[0]):
    df = df[ ~((df['ID'] == rdf['ID'].iloc[i]) & (df['SEQNO'] >= rdf['SEQNO'].iloc[i]) ) ]
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on improving the function. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

df['mask'] = np.where(df['DESCRIP'].eq('XYZ'), 1, np.nan)

df['mask'] = df.groupby('ID')['mask'].ffill()

df = df.loc[df['mask'].ne(1), ['ID', 'SEQNO', 'DESCRIP']]
```

In short - we mark rows with `XYZ`, then forward fill within groups, then filter out marked rows.

Output:

```py
   ID SEQNO              DESCRIP
0  A1     1         This is test
1  A1     2          To check DF
4  B1     1  Hello, How are you.
```

Comment: This is the best option. Find the first `XYZ` and replace it to a NaN and force all values below to have a NaN within that group. Delete all NaNs and you have the remaining records.

Comment: WOW !!! You are the champ @Grzegorz-skibinski.
It's super fast, even for 20 mil. its getting completed within 10 seconds.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It ain't pretty, but I would do:

```py
(
    df.assign(drop=lambda df: 
        df.groupby('ID')['DESCRIP']
          .apply(lambda x: 
            x.str.contains('XYZ')
                 .cumsum()
                 .astype(bool))
    ).loc[lambda df: ~df['drop']]
)
```

The groupby collects data based on the unique values of the ID column.

Within each group, the drop column is assigned 1 if the DESCRIP column contains the string "XYZ", which is then cumulatively summed within that group.

Then the `.loc` accessor selects any row where the `drop` column is False.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but its very slow. My dataset having approx. 20 million rows.